# AngularJS using ng-repeat to display Hierarchical Data

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I've been trying to build a nice way to represent hierarchical data in my application. I've created a slide effect for some bootstrap badges I am using to display some sub-categories using AngularJS.

I've created (with some help from you stackoverflow-ers!) the following example which works for data of the type parent and child. ie. You can't be a parent and child at the same time, which is needed for my real world example.

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="category in categories"
        ng-init="isChild = category.category_type == 'child'"
        ng-show="category.category_show"
        class="badge-slider">

      <span class="badge {{ isChild ? 'badge-c' : 'badge-p' }}"
            ng-click="isChild || updateResults(category)"
            ng-bind="category.category_name">
      </span>

    </li>
  </ul>
```

I am struggling to understand what is the best way to change the code so it is able to work for the additional 'parent and child' category_type. This 'parent and child' category_type is needed for creating a way to browse a directory structure.

In the example above, it relies on the boolean value 'isChild' and the ternary operator, which doesn't work when we introduce the 'parent and child' category_type.

Anyone got any ideas?

Here is a link to a PLNKR which demonstrates the sliding functionality working for simple the parent-child relationship: http://plnkr.co/edit/9CiXW1YAoPj80x6PtBW3

**EDIT 1:**

I've created another PLNKR to handle the 3-tier nature of the hierarchical relationship. It works fine, except it doesn't display 'parent and child' elements with the corresponding badge....   http://plnkr.co/edit/YoRI578GHE91t6torCUt

Comment: This is a response to your "EDIT 1".
The 'parent and child' elements are not displayed with the corresponding badge as your evaluation criteria is not correct. 

`span class="badge {{ isChild ? 'badge-c' : 'badge-p' }}"` clearly says that if it is child then apply badge-c else for all other cases apply badge-p
..
I had addressed this in my plunker :http://plnkr.co/edit/UfwL3A9DK2TSmSn5dHX6?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I solved this:

1. Modified `categories` data structure
2. Created inline angular template in html file
3. Create new CSS class for "parent and child" elements

You can view the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UfwL3A9DK2TSmSn5dHX6?p=preview)

Here is a Snapshot of the result:
[image]

Comment: Hi Dinesh - that looks really cool. I noticed that the indent of 10px in the CSS has been hard-coded. Anyway to dynamically indent the badges dependent on the value of {{category.category_depth}}, for example??

Comment: The reason it should be dynamic is because we don't know how many sub-categories there may be in any tree....

Comment: @TomO'Brien - Yes in an ideal scenario css indent should by dynamic. The solution i posted was only for a demo scenario.
Alternatively, you could check the Angular UI Tree shared on GitHub http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/ .

You will have to restructure your categories data structure such that each element in 'categories'  contain name, type, show and child{} properties, where child{} is similar to a 'categories' element. In essence, a 'catogories' element could contain another 'categories' element and so on, recursive!

Comment: Hi Dinesh - new to this angularjs stuff, and this is the first ng-template i have used. Been reading your code. I am a little confused, so bear with me. I didn't understand what the <ul> in the template was doing - is it necessary? I created a fork of your PLNKR without it and it seems to work fine without it. Am I missing something? (Probably about 100 IQ points....) Here is the new version: http://plnkr.co/edit/jAD4uo5vuct45TxwwsGQ

Comment: Hi Tom, the <ul> can be avoided in this case. I was working on a similar scenario but the displaying of children had some conditions so I had put the <ul> tag with ng-if for conditional display. My apologies to have got you confused. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is not currently hierarchical.  I would suggest a structure such as this for your categories list (probably a better name name), where each element in an array has an array "children" as a property.

```
$scope.categories = [
  {category_name:"apples", children: [
    {category_name:"bramble", children: [
      {category_name:"red"},
      {category_name:"green"}
    ]},
    {category_name:"granny smiths"},
    {category_name:"pink lady"}
  ]},
  {category_name:"oranges", children: [
    {category_name:"satsuma"},
    {category_name:"nectarine"},
    {category_name:"mandarin"}
  ]}
];
```

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dhBGKgdEpqkfAWkdfhk9?p=preview) of an inefficient way to represent this (templates and directive would be a more effective way to work on the recursive aspect versus doing it manually).